# Bash - no output

Tags: bash

name of file **01.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
test=$(top -b -i -E=g -n 1 > top.txt | grep "%Cpu" | cut -b 9-13)
echo "${test}"
```

The command "top -b -i -E=g -n 1 > top.txt | grep "%Cpu" | cut -b 9-13" on its own appears to work as intended.

**I am attempting to save the output of the command above to test variable**. But in this format test returns nothing. (Example: echo {$test} ; output: {} )

I have been unable to figure out why the command in test=$() does not return a value. Am I being a dummy?

Fixes so far:

I have tried a number of options, even changing grep and cut to awk with the similar results. I changed to this method because awk was being inconsistent. I was having awk grab the second row second element but if CPU usage is 100.0 there is no space between the ":" $Cpu(s):100.0 .

Changed /bin/bash to /usr/bin/bash env. -no dice

Added **export** test=$(). -no dice

Comment: The output from `top` can only be sent to one place, either a file (`> top.txt`) or another command (`| grep ...`). The way you've written it, the file redirect takes precedence, so nothing is sent to the rest of the pipeline. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Good first question. Not sure why someone downvoted. (It's not perfect), but sample code, formatted correctly, some discussion of what else attempted. In my book, keep posting! ( try replace `> top.txt` with `| tee top.txt | grep ...`), although it's not clear why you are saving the output. `var=$(top .. | grep ....)` should give you what you need for storing output to a variable. BTW, `test` is a built in command in the shell, best to develop a habit of using `myTest=...` etc to avoid a hidden conflict some day. Good luck.

Comment: You don't feed any input to `grep`, so _grep_ does not produce any output, and therefore `cut` does not get any input either.

Comment: `test` is a command in POSIX shell (and bash) synonymous with `[ .. ]` While you can override it by assignment, overriding keywords is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
test=$(top -b -i -E=g -n 1 | grep "%Cpu" | cut -b 9-13)
echo "${test}"
```

run without > top.txt

Answer (score 0):

You don't feed any input to `grep`, so *grep* does not produce any output, and therefore `cut` does not get any input either. If you need the output of `top` saved into a file, send it to `tee`:

```
top -b -i -E=g -n 1|tee top.txt|grep ...|cut ...
```